# How to get a Flex ComboBox to see its own SHOW event

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, combobox, mxml

Welcome ME to stackoverflow!

I have (tried both mx & spark) to create an encapsulated library object based on ComboBox, which appears in multiple places (in a viewstack) of a 4.6.0 Flex app. I would like it to fetch a fresh data collection from the server every time it "re-appears" (eg from flipping back and forth in the viewstack). The goal is to keep the contents of the dropdown in sync between all the different instances.

Unfortunately, the SHOW event apparently does not trigger when the component is revealed. I've tried the `show=""` attribute of the component's MXML tag, and also `this.addEventListener(FlexEvent.SHOW,foo)` in the components `init()` function. I can tell from both a trace and behavior that nothing's happening.

Am I using the wrong event? I can populate the dataprovider just fine on creationcomplete, I just want to refresh it every time the ComboBox shows back up on the stage again.

Here's the component in it's most simplest form:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<s:ComboBox xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"  
 xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"  
 xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"  
 show="trace('I have shown!')">  
</s:ComboBox>
```

I've searched around quite a bit, and can't find anything - or am missing the perfect keywords. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, it's the wrong event. SHOW is specific to when a component's visible property becomes true. So I can set a visible attribute on this tag - that's true for the correct selectedIndex of the parent viewstack. But I can't believe that's the best answer here.

Comment: It depends on how you show/hide the component. If you do it through visibility `show` will do the trick (as you already found out). If it's done through adding/removing the object to/from the displaylist, try `add`, `added` or `addedToStage`. Not sure which one of these events is dispatched when exactly.